# How to implement out-of-order prefix string matching

Tags: database, algorithm

I'm trying to implement out-of-order, prefix string matching. The best example of this would be Quora which queries for the string you typed into the search box using out of order prefix matching (not quite google search though because google search matches all of the string you've typed so far).

Example:
query: "sat"
might return:

> What is the highest SAT score you can receive
>
> What is the distance of Saturn from Earth?
>
> He sat on the bench

But searching for "core" (the last 4 letters of the word score) will not return any results.

What algorithm and database would you recommend for this problem? I'm planning on using this on a website in an AJAX-y UI (so as the user types in letters, results will keep getting mor refined.). I'm fine with any sort of database, and this is for a pet-project. Thanks!

Comment: fwiw quora wrote their own - http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-open-source-solution-for-implementing-fast-auto-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trie data structure with a regular and a reverse dictionnary: http://phpir.com/tries-and-wildcards. There are also compressed tries like crit-bit, radix and patricia tries.

Answer (score 0):

Use Trie based indexing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie. Basically root-> s will store the indexes of all sentences that have at least one word starting with s, root-> s->a will store the indexes of all sentences that have at least one word starting with sa ... so on. It is a good idea to preprocess the list (limit to top k words, and show results related to top used words and so on).